# Adding Multi-tenancy to Django Viewflow App

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-viewflow

I am creating a Django Viewflow application and I am trying to add multi-tenancy to it but I am not sure how to go about it. I am building the application on Django with MySQL (I cannot move from MySQL).

The django-multitenant package provides a means to do this by using passing the tenant model to each of my custom models, i.e.

```
class Products(TenantModel):
    ....
```

Is there a way to configure Django Viewflow to do the same?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit from abstract viewflow model classes and write you own frontend in that case.

Comment: Thanks @kmmbvnr. I'll look to see if that will work for us.